# "they get on like a house on fire"

Tags: present-perfect

*Those two met last Saturday at the party, and because they were both into juggling they get on like a house on fire.*

This is an exemplary sentence explaining the idiom "get on like a house on fire". I would like to ask why the present simple is used in second part of the sentence ("get on like…"). I would choice the present perfect ("they have got on like…"). I suppose that from the context it is clear that their mutual sympathy stil persists. Or when using "get on…" I would await the same tense in the first part, i.e. "they are both into juggling…"

Comment: I still think of *exemplary* as implying *a **good** example*, so it doesn't really work for me with your cited text, which I think is exceptionally ***poor*** writing.

Comment: They **are** both into juggling...  yes. or "they **got** on.."

Comment: Do you ever upvote any answers, @bart-leby?

Comment: Yes, I do. Almost every answer. I do not understand your comment. Do you think that I am ungrateful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiom "Get on (like a house on fire)" can be used in the present, the simple past, and the perfect.

> (When they met) they got on like a house on fire.

doesn't say whether their relationship is continuing - it worked then.

> (They met last week and) they get on like a house on fire.

says that their good relationship is continuing.

> (Since they met last week) they have got on like a house on fire.

is very similar in meaning to the previous example.

Answer (score 0):

[*get on*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+on) is an idiom here.

> get on (with someone)
>   to be friends with someone; to have a good relationship with someone. (The friendship is always assumed to be good unless it is stated to be otherwise.) *How do you get on with John? I get along with John just fine. We get along*.
>   <sub>[McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs via TFD]</sub>

Similar idioms are *get along* (a bit more formal) and *get it on* (much more intimate).

Saying the relationship is like a "house on fire" is making a simile to how a fire feeds on the house. Meaning one person strongly encourages the other.

Comment: Hmm... do you mean that saying *We got along* or *We got on* is incorrect? (An example from a novel: *Mum was surprised when we got back home so early. 'What happened?' she asked. 'Didn't you get on with Bruno?' Alice smiled at her. 'Oh, we got on just fine,' she said. 'We got on so well that we're meeting him again tomorrow morning.'*)

Comment: Not sure what I was thinking. Scratch that.

Comment: But what about tenses? Do you find their usage in the sentnce OK?

Comment: *get on* is more likely describing an ongoing relationship rather than a momentary one. In reading the quote I don't think it refers to Saturday only. As such I wouldn't use "get on" in the past tense. But it might just be me. Could you add the source, or some additional context to your question?

Comment: @DamkerngT. I think "got along" is OK, but "got on" seems wrong to me somehow.

Comment: *got on* would be perfectly idiomatic.  They got on very well. They got along very well.